# pass comma separated input parameter to SSRS Reporting Service

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a web page which a textbox where user enter invoice no. and press a show button 
A SSRS report is then displayed to the user which has a header like inv_no, address ,name etc and details of that invoice is show down to the header in the tabular format.,I was sucessfully able to acheive this requirment using two dataset one which

```
ds_header_inv_dtl parameter as @invoiceno and 
ds_detail_inv_info parameter as @invoiceno
```

Now the problem is that the requirement has changed , User will enter Multiple Invoice No. with comma separator and Press show report Button .
same report should display as header information then details information and page break and then again header info --> details info and page break and so on.

Is it possible to create XML file for ssrs report ?

Please help me how should i achieve this kind of requirement.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to create an xml file? the usual way to do this is to have a parameter which is a comma separated list of invoice numbers. you pass the list as a string, then convert it to distinct values in sql (see 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitjet/archive/2009/12/11/sql-server-comma-separated-string-to-table.aspx for examples of how to do this)

the other way is to create a report with a parameter that accepts multiple values. you cannot then set that parameter trough url, but if you use the SSRS web services to generate the report you can.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not misunderstanding your intent but if you just want SSRS to display a simple table, you can have it generate a table object - no need to generate the `XML` `.RDL` file. There is an `Export to XML` option from the hosted and executed report, however.

If you just want to allow users to dynamically add records, then I'm doing something similar now and this was my solution. I apologize that it's fairly bass-ackwards and convoluted, but it works really well for me when I can't get time web dev time for a more elegant presentation.

First:
UDF to take a delimited string for the invoice numbers you want and convert to a searchable text array

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnDelimitedListToVarcharTableVariable]
(
    @DelimitedList nvarchar(max),
    @Delimiter varchar(1)
)
RETURNS @tbl table(SplitValues nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DelimiterPos int
-- Find the first comma
    SET @DelimiterPos = PATINDEX( '%,%', @DelimitedList)
-- If a delimiter was found, @DelimiterPos will be > 0.
    WHILE @DelimiterPos > 0
        BEGIN
-- Insert the value between the start of the string and the first delimiter, into the table variable.
            INSERT INTO @tbl(SplitValues) SELECT CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM((SUBSTRING(@DelimitedList, 1, @DelimiterPos -1)))) AS nvarchar(max))
-- Trim the string of the first value and delimiter.
            SET @DelimitedList = SUBSTRING(@DelimitedList, @DelimiterPos +1, LEN(@DelimitedList) - @DelimiterPos)
-- Look for the next delimiter in the string.
            SET @DelimiterPos = PATINDEX( '%,%', @DelimitedList)
        END
-- Ensure the last / only value in the @DelimitedList string gets inserted into the table variable.
    INSERT INTO @Tbl(SplitValues) SELECT CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM((@DelimitedList))) AS nvarchar(max))
    RETURN
END;
```

Second:
Create a parameter in your SSRS report called `param_DelimitedList`. It should be text datatype with a default value of blank string.

Third:
Create your dataset

```
Create proc spGetInvoices
    @param_DelimitedList varchar( max )
as
begin
    Select
        tbl.InvoiceNumber
        ,tbl.*
    from MyTable tbl
    where cast( tbl.InvoiceNumber as varchar(max) ) in ( select SplitValues from dbo.fnDelimitedListToVarcharTableVariable( @param_DelimitedList, ',' ) );
end;
```

Fourth:
Create a Tablix table object in your SSRS report with the desired fields from your dataset `spGetInvoices`

The user should be able to type in a list of invoice numbers into the parameter box and have the corresponding data returned to the Tablix table object.

The code works well in `SQL Server 2008-R2` and `Report Builder 3.0`. I hope it helps you.